# Gradle clean install - Task 'install' not found in root project

Tags: java, gradle, gradlew

I am trying to build the application using gradle
`gradlew clean install`

while executing the above command got error as,
**Task 'install' not found in root project**

As per the documentation, **plugin - maven** is removed under gradle 7.4 . So I am using **plugin - maven-publish** which is recommended for 7.4

Currently I am using below versions
Java - 11
Gradle - 7.4

Please let me know if there is any solution for the issue

Answer (score 0):

its difficult to guess cause it's not visible the actual gradle.

I had a similar issue when I passed from 5.5 to 7.4.2. The error was the same: Task 'install' not found in root project.

I had just to change all the 'compile' into 'implementation' in the dependencies declaration to execute a complete migration as it is written below.
Then by "build" the project all the dependency has been downloaded and indexed.

> The usage of the compile and runtime configurations in the Java ecosystem plugins has been discouraged since Gradle 3.4.
> These configurations are used for compiling and running code from the main source set. Other sources sets create similar configurations (e.g. testCompile and testRuntime for the test source set), should not be used either. The implementation, api, compileOnly and runtimeOnly configurations should be used to declare dependencies and the compileClasspath and runtimeClasspath configurations to resolve dependencies.

ref: [change compile](https://docs.gradle.org/7.0/userguide/upgrading_version_5.html#dependencies_should_no_longer_be_declared_using_the_compile_and_runtime_configurations)

However, the Gradle task install is part of the deprecated Gradle Maven plugin (maven). You should use the modern Gradle Maven Publish plugin (maven-publish) and its task publishToMavenLocal.

> For integration with a local Maven installation, it is sometimes useful to publish the module into the Maven local repository (typically at $USER_HOME/.m2/repository), along with its POM file and other metadata. In Maven parlance, this is referred to as 'installing' the module.

ref:
[deprecation install](https://docs.gradle.org/7.0/userguide/publishing_maven.html#publishing_maven:install)

!! also pay attention to the other deprecated task and the new sintaxes. You will find details in the same docs